# React Native animation useEffect hook with dependencies array creates infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-animated

I am trying to figure out how to make eslint with the rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` happy and also use the build in `Animated` library in react native to make animations with useEffect.

The following code should highlight the button when clicked, by overlaying it with a colored view.

```js
const Component = props => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      Animated.timing(opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }).start();
    } else {
      setOpacity(new Animated.Value(0))
    }
  }, [active, opacity]); // <- Works fine without `opacity`, but eslint wants this

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor: "blue", opacity}} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> setActive(!active)} />  
    </View>
  )
};
```

Is there any way of doing this (with useCallback, useMemo, etc.) without disabling the rule?

Comment: If you don’t include it `Animated` will never use the update `opacity` value.

Comment: It works without including it in the array.

Comment: May you make a [mcve] showing that? It could be that it updates when `active` updates?

Comment: How can I make an example for React Native?

Comment: An example for react hooks can be made without react native.

Comment: This is a react native specific problem. The animated library increases the value of opacity when the animation starts. I don't think that I can show you the problem without the React Native Animated library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `setOpacity`, instead you can use `setValue`:

```
opacity.setValue(0)
```

There is also no need to add `opacity` to dependencies, because it never changes. ESLint doesn't always get it right.

Comment: I know, that I don't have to add it. But i don't want to disable the rule. The setOpacity part isn't important to me ...

Comment: You can leave it, won't matter if you don't call `setOpacity`

Comment: I edited the question. The else block does not matter. When I add the opacity to the dependency array (and I definitely want that, because otherwise my editor will complain), it makes a loop. This happens because animated interpolates the value from 0 to 1 on click. Can I make it work with useCallback or useMemo somehow?

Comment: The loop happens because precisely because of the else block. If there is not `setOpacity` there is no loop. Try it.